# Change double quotes to single in java but with some restrictions

Tags: java, string

I need to change double quotes to single quotes in java but having some restrictions.

E.g.: Consider this

```
' i love "apple" and "banana" very much'.
```

I don't want to change "apple" and "banana" double quotes to single quotes.

Another one:

```
"Hi! What's up?"
```

Output:

```
'Hi! What's up?'
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Please remove `javascript` tag. `javascript` != `java`

Comment: Do you only want to replace " when its on the beginning or end of a string? Or do you have any other logic you have to follow?

Comment: I want to remove when it is on the beginning and on the end .

Comment: You need to identify specific rules and put it into code otherwise you cannot decide in the first place what to replace and what not.

Answer (score 0):

If this strings are processed line by line then this wont be a problem. You can just make sure that the first and last characters are all `'`. You may check the [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html) documentation, it has a lot of methods to do this.

But if you are dealing with paragraph or sentences then this can be tricky. For this you can use Natural Language Processing (NLP) there are many java implementations of it just do a google and you can find one.